movie about masked vigilante called "Scarecrow"
When I was in grammar school around 1980 they showed us a movie about a masked man similar to Zorro. I believed it opened with a scene in which he and another man fled on horseback while a song was sung in which the word "scarecrow" was repeated. I understood this to be the name of the masked hero. I believe there were several pursuits on horseback and probably some swordplay.
The masks which Scarecrow and his companion wore covered not just the eyes but the whole face. I think they hung loose and had a horrible face painted on them.
In another scene a man was hanged. I think it was in an inn. It was probably for betraying his comrades. Once the noose was around his neck, the lights were put out and he was hoisted up. After a brief pause, the lights were again lit and we saw his motionless feet at the top of the frame. But once everyone else had left two men let him down and revived him. I believe the masked hero both hanged (as some kind of subterfuge) and revived him.
In another scene two or three men were before a magistrate charged with smuggling. A gentleman came into the courtroom and asked the judge if, purely for form's sake, the contents of the wine barrels which they had been conveying had been examined. Men were sent to break them open. These returned and reported to the court that the barrels contained sea water. Someone said, "as far as I know there is no law prohibiting the transportation of seawater" and the men were discharged.
I have been unable to identify this film though I have searched in the IMDB using possible titles and by entering key words from the scenes described above, but so far without success. 

What you are describing sounds like it could be The Scarecrow of Romney Marsh originally from Walt Disney's Wonderful World of Color (1964). Production was re-edited in the 1970's for theatrical release.

Dr.Syn, a country priest leads a rebel band against the King's naval
  press gangs. Press gangs (impressment) roam the country side beating
  young men into submission or unconsciousness, usually at local inns
  and pubs, in order to enslave them in the Royal British Navy. Dr. Syn
conceals his secret identity behind a sackcloth mask, and carries on
  activities ala Scarlet Pimpernel and Zorro from his parish base.


The one I was thinking of when I read the question, starring Patrick McGoohan of "The Prisoner" fame.  In the UK release it was call "Dr. Syn, Alias the Scarecrow"

@TheWanderingDevManager Yes.  Wasn't that on the tv series, Wonderful world of color?  Dr. Syn, Alias the Scarecrow was the name of the episode wasn't it?
